# Getting Exception while running Odd even program using multiple thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to run below written program. But Here I am getting exception as

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
at main.java.OddEven$even.run(OddEven.java:16)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am unable to find reason behind exception.

Execption is occuring in notify method. We get IllegalMonitorStateException in notify method only when current thread does not own the lock object.

```
public class OddEven {

private Integer count = 0;
Object ob = new Object();

class even implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
            while (count % 2 == 0) {
                synchronized (ob) {
                if (count % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(count++);
                    notify();
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
}

class odd implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            while (count % 2 != 0) {
                synchronized (ob) {
                if (count % 2 != 0) {
                    System.out.println(count++);
                    notify();
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    OddEven t1 = new OddEven();
    Thread e = new Thread(t1.new even());
    Thread o = new Thread(t1.new odd());
    e.start();
    o.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call `notify()` on an object you need to have a lock on that object, i.e. be in a block synchronized on that object. You are in a synchronized block, but you are synchronizing on `ob`, while you are calling `notify()`on `this`.

You either have to also use `ob` for your `notify()`and `wait()` calls, or synchronize on `this`.

Comment: To clearify, if you don't call `notify()` or `wait()` on an object, you implicitly call it on `this`

Comment: I am not getting expected output here. Which should be 1 2 3 4 .. . I am just getting  1 2. Can you help me in figuring out mistake ?  I have correct my code and It is not throwing exception.

Comment: Are you sure you call `wait()` on `ob` too?

Comment: It is working now after calling ob.notify() and ob.wait()